# How to add a specific icon from a different version on Font Awesome?

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Font Awesome (v4.7.x) does not have the **Gitter** icon. They introduced it from v5. Now, without entirely updating all of the fontawesome files or using the v5 cdn, how can I just use the `fa-gitter` icon?

Comment: Why would you not update fontawesome? I assume you installed it with a package manager, just tell that package manager to update it for you and peg that new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not want so say it's not possible - but I'd say it's beyond most FA-Users (including myself) to embark on such an adventure.  I don't think one could get away with "just one icon" - there's always CSS involved...and the CSS from FA4 and FA5 (may) overlap and could cause further trouble - this really feels like an ugly can of worms.

Your time is probably better spent researching and eliminating reasons for not upgrading than trying to mix the two.

Comment: Yes. That should be an ideal approach. Upgraded version.

Answer (score 1):

You can include this stylesheet link in your HTML code and after try this class.

Link :- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Font awesome Gitter Class :-

See Here is the live Example :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "demo">
    <i class="fab fa-gitter"></i>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well I don't actually want to load the whole css from cdn. Cause I already have the v4.7.x. Is it possible to load only the `fa-gitter`from v5 some way?

Comment: you can try this one to solve your issue Link is here:- https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4